# POST com todos valores do SELECT *

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, crud

Preciso fazer um `POST` para uma página (*cadastrar.php*) com todos dados do `SELECT *` para depois fazer o `INSERT` com todos dados.

Precisa ser nessa ordem, pois recebo `GET`'s de páginas anteriores (data e turma).

Eu preciso inserir dados no banco de dados da seguinte maneira:

1. Selecionar dia
2. Selecionar turma
3. Exibir todos alunos e selecionar quais faltaram

O que pensei, foi fazer um `SELECT *` marcar quais alunos faltaram, fazer um POST com os dados para cadastrar.php (nesse arquivo faria o INSERT na data e turma selecionada).

**No meu resultado atual o `<form action="cadastrar.php"` só recebe um valor, como faço para receber todos?**

presença.php:

```
    <form class="row g-3 align-items-center" id="cadastro" method="POST" action="./cadastrar.php">

          <div class="table table-responsive">
              <table class="table mt-2">
                <thead>
                  <th>Nome</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                </thead>
            <?php

                $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM alunos");
                while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="nome" value="'.$col['nome'].'">';
                echo '<td>'.$col['nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td><div class="form-check form-switch">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="status" checked>
                  </div></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                
                }
              ?>

              </table>
          <input type="submit">
         </div>
    </form>
```

cadastrar.php:

```
<?php
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        if(!isset($status)){
            $status = "falta";
        }else{
            $status = "presença";
        }
        
        echo $nome;
        echo $status;
    ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Se você quer que todos os alunos e seus respectivos status sejam enviados para cadastrar.php, você precisa mudar a estrutura do seu formulário e dos inputs.

Em vez de ter um input com o nome "nome" e outro com o nome "status" para cada linha da tabela, você deve usar arrays com índices numéricos para cada aluno. Algo como:

```
<form class="row g-3 align-items-center" id="cadastro" method="POST" action="./cadastrar.php">

    <div class="table table-responsive">
        <table class="table mt-2">
            <thead>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <?php
                $i = 0;
                $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM alunos");
                while($col = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="alunos['.$i.'][nome]" value="'.$col['nome'].'">';
                    echo '<td>'.$col['nome'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td><div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="alunos['.$i.'][status]" checked>
                    </div></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    $i++;
                }
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

E no cadastrar.php você pode usar um loop para percorrer cada aluno e fazer o INSERT no banco de dados:

```
<?php
    $alunos = $_POST['alunos'];
    foreach($alunos as $aluno) {
        $nome = $aluno['nome'];
        $status = $aluno['status'];
        if(!isset($status)){
            $status = "falta";
        }else{
            $status = "presença";
        }
        echo $nome;
        echo $status;
    }
?>
```

Para tornar ainda mais completo, você pode adicionar os inputs para data e turma no formulário para enviar para cadastrar.php também e usar esses valores para fazer o INSERT na tabela correta.

Answer (score -3):

Aqui está um exemplo de como você poderia melhorar o seu código para tratar os dados de forma mais segura e evitar erros:

```
<form class="row g-3 align-items-center" id="cadastro" method="POST" action="./cadastrar.php">
    <div class="table table-responsive">
        <table class="table mt-2">
            <thead>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <?php
                // Conectando ao banco de dados
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "username";
                $password = "password";
                $dbname = "myDB";

                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                // Preparando a query
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT nome FROM alunos");
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();

                while($col = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value="'.$col['nome'].'">';
                    echo '<td>'.$col['nome'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td><div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="status[]">
                    </div></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Usei prepared statements para evitar ataques SQL Injection, e também para garantir a segurança dos dados.
Alterei o checkbox para que ele não esteja marcado por padrão, e adicionei o atributo "name" "status[]" para que o PHP possa identificar quais checkboxes foram marcados e quais não foram.
Alterei o name do input para "nome[]" para que todos os nomes sejam enviados juntos para o arquivo "cadastrar.php"
Adicionei um botão de "Atualizar" para indicar a ação do formulário
Adicionei tratamento de erros para garantir que o código PHP se comporte de forma esperada em caso de erros.

Aqui está um exemplo de como você poderia escrever o código PHP para processar os dados do formulário e atualizar o status dos alunos no banco de dados:

```
<?php
    // Conectando ao banco de dados
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // Recebendo os dados do formulário
    $nomes = $_POST['nome'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    // Preparando a query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE alunos SET status = ? WHERE nome = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $status_value, $nome_value);

    foreach($nomes as $i => $nome) {
        $nome_value = $nome;
        $status_value = isset($status[$i]) ? 'Ativo' : 'Inativo';

        $stmt->execute();
    }

    echo "Status atualizado com sucesso";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Aqui recebe os dados do formulário via $_POST, como os nomes e status dos alunos.
Utilizei uma prepared statement para atualizar o status dos alunos no banco de dados